# Use of a known solution to find another ODE Book explanation

Tags: calculus

Use of a known solution to find another: 
$P(x) \frac{dy(x)}{dx}+y Q(x)+\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=0$

$y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ be the solutions, now if we assume that the first solution can be found with simple inspection we can use a procedure to find the other one.

Now the procedure that is used to find the second solution; $y_2(x)=v(x) y_1(x)$

Now we assume that this is a solution. 
Now if we substitute back into the equation $y_2'(x)$ and $y_2''(x)$, and rearrange we have 
$$v \left(P(x) y_1'(x)+y_1 Q(x)+y_1''(x)\right)+v'(x) \left(y_1 P(x)+2  y_1'\right)+y_1 v''(x)$$

Now this is where I realised that I am missing some crucial information

The book says that since $y_1(x)$ is a solution to

$ \left(P(x) y_1'(x)+y_1 Q(x)+y_1''(x)\right)$ 
it reduces $$v \left(P(x) y_1'(x)+y_1 Q(x)+y_1''(x)\right)+v'(x) \left(y_1 P(x)+2  y_1'\right)+y_1 v''(x)$$ to
$$v'(x) \left(y_1 P(x)+2  y_1'\right)+y_1 v''(x)=0$$

Now let's say that $y_1(x)$ does not solve the equation, lets say that there does not excist a function that solves the equation how would that effect the reduction. I am struggling with understanding why we need a solution, given ODE equtions is set equal to zero I thought this would be sufficient for the reduction.

Comment: The idea is "given one solution to this second order ODE, can we describe a method to find another?" What you have shown above is part of the working to find $y_2$ from $y_1$. If $y_1$ is *not* a solution, then the procedure given wouldn't work and the preliminary premise ("given one solution") isn't met. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I mean I get the idea, my problem is what conditions is needed for the reduction. Since it is equal to zero can I always just think of it as multiplying v(x) with zero, or would I need a general solution before I do such a reduction. It is only the reduction, the and what conditions that are needed for doing this.

Comment: $y_1$ being **one** solution to the ODE is a sufficient condition. $y_1$ is not a general solution to the ODE. A general solution would be of the form $c_3y_3 + c_4y_4$ where $y_3, y_4$ are two linearly independent solutions of the ODE $c_3, c_4$ are arbitrary real numbers. (I have used the labels $3$ and $4$ instead of $1$ and $2$ to make it clear that a general solution is not necessarily a linear sum of $y_1$ and $y_2$. However if this procedure works, then $c_1y_1 + c_2y_2$ would also be an expression of the general solution.)

Comment: Okey, I am explaining myself poorly. forget about finding another solution, imagine we have s(x)*(ODE)+K(x)=0, now in this case lets say that the ODE=0, would I need to find the solution to reduce this s(x)*(ODE)+K(x)=0 to K(x)=0. Or could i just substitute ODE with 0, just because it is stated or would I need to find a solution before this would be true.?

Comment: *If* you have a function $y$ such that the ODE in $y$ were equation to zero, then you could conclude $K(x) = 0$. And that's what is going on here. Note that until we know there is a function $y$ such that the ODE is equal to zero, we can't manipulate the ODE as though it were equal to zero. By analogy, there is no real number $x$ such that $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$. If we had an equation $s(x)(x^2 + x + 1) + k(x) = 0$, we can't conclude that $k(x) = 0$ just because we wrote down earlier the symbols "$x^2 + x + 1 = 0$". We first need to know there *is* an $x$ such that the quadratic equals zero.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted to confirm. I'm sorry for my poor output of my question!